# how to run action after the competion of another

Tags: android, json, parsing, app-inventor

I'm trying to run an action but only after another completes.
What i have is a yql to pull json off a web site, and parse the information i need.
Problem is that part of the info I'm trying to pull is a picture.
So basically the process goes like so:

1. YQL request
2. results in Json
3. parse the information from the Json to be the web URL for the picture
4. save to temp data / label1 for testing
5. set picture1 to the URL from Tamp data and pull the picture from the web

Problem with this is the actions have completed before the URL came down and was parsed. resulting in the url being there but not the picture.

I have tried using multiple if statements to get it to work but haven't had success.

I cant use a timer because of the varying internet connection speeds on android devices. i would have to set it for the lowest possible connection and that could be 10+ seconds.

I've been working on this for almost a week with out any success outside of a timer.

Any suggestions?

thank you

Comment: Actually I don't understand the problem... you parse the JSON inside a `Web.GotText` event to get the URL of the picture and set `image1.picture=URL`. After a few seconds (depending on the internet connection and the picture size) the image should appear. If that does not work, a screenshot of your blocks would help. You might want to follow up [in your other thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/programming-with-app-inventor/QvSFo-T3O2o/1kcREmHCoX4J)